# ios custom navigation (vertical) advice

Tags: ios

I have an idea for an ios5 navigation I'm doing on an app and I thought it wise to get some *constructive criticism* from `SOF` about my idea.

Idea:

- `UIView` containing 6 or so buttons stacked vertically
- `UIButtons` have a selected state.
- Buttons static/global keeps track of last touched button and always resets the last touched button when a new `UIButton` is touched.

Question:
Can you read and access the children of the UIView? 
eg. (pseudocode)

```
for (i in [myView children]) {
    [[myView getChildAt:i] doSomethingToThisButton];
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here's the non-pseudocode (well, mostly):

```
for (UIView *subview in [myView subviews]) {
    [subview doSomethingToThisButton];
}
```

Or, if you prefer

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myView.subviews count]; i++) {
    [[myView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] doSomethingToThisButton];
}
```

Don't make your last touched button a static variable because then you can only have one such control in your whole app. Make a UIView subclass  to act as the container for your buttons, and have the last selected view be a property of that class.

You may also want to make your containing view a subclass of UIControl instead of UIView, then you can make it send events and bind to it using drag and drop in interface builder, just like a regular control (e.g. a button).

Comment: Good sir, you are the recipient of the majority of my +1s as of late.